# Rxjava and work manager chained asychronous calls

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-workmanager

Update: This was how my old insertIntoDb method looked like which didn't work :

```
private Completable insertIntoDb(List<ArticleEntity> articleItemEntities) {
    return database.articleDao().insertArticles(articleItemEntities)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

I changed it to the following and now it works :

```
 private void insertIntoDbNew(List<ArticleEntity> articleItemEntities) {
        mCompositeDisposable.add(
                database.articleDao().insertArticles(articleItemEntities)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe());

    }
```

I don't know why but now it works. Sure the worker completes before the database insert completes but that doesn't seem to be a problem which I believed before.

End of update.

I'm new to reactive programming. My goal is to schedule a work manager to do 4 Actions then return a result using RxJava2. Here are the tasks I want to perform

1. Do a web api call.
2. Structure the data we get from the API call.
3. Insert it into our local room database.
4. When everything is complete signal `Result.success()` back to the Job so it knows that everything went ok and can terminate.

So my preferred method would look something like this.

```java
public Result doWork(){
    return api.get("URL") responseData -> structureData(responseData) structuredData -> insertIntoDB(structuredData) -> Result.success()
}
```

I'm using RxJava2 and the RxWorker class.

Below is my current solution. Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?

```java
public class DownloadWorker extends RxWorker {

    @Override
    public Single<Result> createWork() {
        return apiService.download("URL")
                .map(response -> processResponse(response))
                .doOnSuccess(data -> insertIntoDb(data))
                .flatMap(response ->
                        allComplete()
                )
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

    Single<Result> allComplete() {
        return Single.just(Result.success());
    }

}
```

It behaves like I want it to. It downloads the data, structures it, then inserts it into the DB then returns `Result.success()`. But I have no idea what I am doing. Am I using RxJava as it was intended?

Also this part bothers me :

```java
.flatMap(response -> allComplete())
```

the response part is superfluous can I remove it somehow?

Comment: What does insertIntoDb() function return?

Comment: It returns a Completable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some improvements to your code:

```java
public class DownloadWorker extends RxWorker {

    @Override
    public Single<Result> createWork() {
        return apiService.download("URL")
                .map(response -> processResponse(response))
                .flatMapCompletable(articleItemEntities -> database.articleDao().insertArticles(articleItemEntities))
                .toSingleDefault(Result.success())
                .onErrorReturnItem(Result.failure())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}
```

In original code, you save data using `doOnSuccess` method which is a side effect. As you mentioned in your comment, `insertIntoDb()` method returns `Completable`. Therefore, I changed `doOnSuccess(data -> insertIntoDb(data))` to `flatMapCompletable(data -> insertIntoDb(data))` which will allow you make sure storing data succeeded and wait until it finishes. As `insertIntoDb()` method returns `Completable` and `createWork()` method has to return `Result`, we have to now change type from `Completable` to `Single<Result>`. Therefore, I used `toSingleDefault` which returns `Result.success()` by default. Also, I added `onErrorReturnItem(Result.failure())` which will allow **RxWorker** to track errors. I hope my answer helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works as intended now :)